# XSSFWorkbook problems to create new XLSX files

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am new to POI, trying to use Apache POI to create xlsx files.

This code:

```
Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Java Books");
```

Throws the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:191)
```

The following dependecies are included in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>
```

How should I use `XSSFWorkbook` to create XLSX file without arguments in the constructor?

PS: `HSSFWorkbook` without arguments in constructor works like a charm, but `HSSFWorkbook` creates only XLS files

Comment: You might have a JAR clash. Are you sure you're having only one version of the POI related JARs? Try clearing maven repository once.

Comment: @Vasan Thanks. You're right

Comment: The problem was solved?